# Client authorization with python backend

Tags: python, security, sockets, authorization

I'm writing panel for administrating nginx (domains, rewrites, etc), svn and other services. For that, i'm writing backend that will work on root (to change nginx configs, reload them, change user passwords, etc), and client (console client, and web app).

App works on unix sockets, and i made very simple protocol for it:

```
\0\0\0\0user\0key\0module\0command\0data\0
```

Well, this is quite simple. Client sends command and data to backend, fox ex:

```
\0\0\0\0morsik\0\0nginx\0add_domain\0www.domain.tld something\0
```

Problem is, how to authenticate that user is really morsik? For web interface i don't have to - web page have it's own authorization so i can sent some key that will work for every user that nobody will know.
Problem is if somebody have access to ssh. Then he could write simple client that will spoof username and then he could change other user configuration.

So, how can i made correct authorization for users?

Comment: You might want to study the book "Applied Cryptography" by Bruce Schneier, first. Likely you will have to use an HMAC with the same key.

Comment: HMAC looks interesting, but if key will be public known there's still possibility of spoof data. Because this is python script, this must be public... or there is other way to store key?

Comment: I think i know how to do this. It'll be system using private keys for users. Users will have .serveradmin.key with their own key with 400 chmod, so other users won't read that. Also, server will contain users.db file with valid keys and users (root:root 400 of course). On www it can be stored in DB (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc).
I'll publish result when it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel.  ;)  I found this discussion enlightening:

- http://cyberelk.net/tim/2007/03/08/cups-unix-domain-sockets-authentication/  Explains the concept of socket auth.
- http://pythonic.pocoo.org/2007/7/7/unix-socket-credentials-with-python Helpful details.
- http://atlee.ca/software/pam/  This might work also, though less convenient.
- Create a group for app admins only, etc.

Comment: That doesn't help me much. I know about using unix auth in python. Problem is how to auth if packet is not corrupted without entering password (if sb is logged into ssh, he probably don't want to enter pass...).

Comment: The first linked article discusses exactly that.

Comment: According to your first link:
>>"The client program — “cancel” or “lp” in this case, or any program that uses libcups for their print dialog such as the Evince document viewer — can pass its UID (numeric ID corresponding to the user name) to the server over the domain socket.
So UID probably can be spoofed here."<< Or i'm wrong? What's the security here to not spoof UID/username?

Comment: "The kernel guarantees that credentials passed in this way cannot be forged."  Mentions reading "man unix 7".  Perhaps this can give you the clues to finish.

Comment: Found another link, adding.  Should get you most of the way there.  Then just get the username from uid and match against the given.

Comment: You can only pass credentials over a Unix socket, which means only the local machine. This does not include a network.

Comment: Using username+uid still can be spoofed if user have access to /etc/passwd. New link tells about checking process id too. It can be enough... client sends pid/username/uid, and server checks if pid belongs to <username> with <uid>.  This probably can't be spoofed unless user find bug in kernel to spoof uid in process. Thanks +1 Anyway i also added HMAC checking. BUT, this can break compability with web panel...

Comment: Correct, the technique answers the question as given.  Sorry I didn't have time to write sample code yesterday.

Comment: Np. i did it by myself today. Thanks for help. Also should for webclient AND terminal client. Webclient sends user key (later will be store in DB), but terminal client pid/uname/uid. This is server code, no client yet...
http://projects.darkserver.it/darkadmin/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=darkadmin&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fdata.py